# find the radius of convergence when $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^\frac{1}{z^n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

find the radius of convergence when
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^\frac{1}{z^n}$$
I do not know if it convrges or diverges. How can I know? 
I tried to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_{n}|}<1$ in order to use one of the conditions of converging. but I got: $e^r < 1$ which leads to $r<0$. Contradiction.

Comment: It's not a power series to begin with, so it's a bit strange to talk about radius of convergence. What is it that you're denoting by $a_n$ here?

Comment: I meant this $$e^\frac{1}{z^n}$$

Comment: I was asked to find the domain of convergence. I thought it was the same as finding the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

If it converges at some point $z,$ then $e^{\frac {1}{z^n}}\to 0\implies {\text{Re}(e^\frac {1}{z^n})}\to 0.$ If $z = re^{i\theta}, 0 \leq\theta < 2\pi$ then the latter is $e^{\frac{\cos n\theta}{r^n}}\to 0,$ but this must mean:
$$\dfrac{\cos(n\theta)}{r^n}\to - \infty$$
. However, this is impossible since $\cos(n\theta)$ will be alternating signs, unless $\theta = 0, \dfrac{\pi}{2,}\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$. But in those case the series is obviously divergent since for example:
$$e^{r^{-n}} > 1,$$
when $\theta = 0$ etc.